# Is this a legal use of global variables in Python?

Tags: python

I've written a small script in Python for simple text manipulation, consisting of a bunch of functions. Some of these functions contain magic numbers or string constants. Is it okay to store them in global variables? I do not intent to modify them, they are more like constants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's legimitate use. You will encounter that in many good Python codes. Just note that the convention is to write the names of such "constants" in `UPPER_CASE`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the preferred way of dealing with constants. At the top of the file you can easily modify them.

You could also move them to a seperate file and use the absolute or relative import.

```
from mypackage import constants as c # absolute -- any Python
from . import constants as c # relative -- Python 2.6+
from .constants import * # Resist any temptation to do this!
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is okay to store constants as global variables. For example Django (a Python web framework) does this with a lot of settings in a settings.py file, which contains globals such as

```
LOGGER = ...
STATIC_DIR = ...
```

etc.